# Python PyPdf 2: Returns empty result for some pdfs

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Hi I have some pdf's that I need to their text info to be extracted. I used the following code below:

```
pdfFileObj = open('abc.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageObj.extractText()
```

But what I get is for a spesific pdf:

'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'

However this code works for some pdf's that I have. What could be the problem? 
Thank you .

Comment: is it possible that there is no text in pdf and what you see is actually an image (e.g. scanned pages)?

Comment: Hi there is actually text and I can even search text inside pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Py2PDF does not pick up the text. A solution I use when this happens is to convert the pdf to jpeg and use an image ocr (tesseract with cv2) to get the text. Another library you could try to use is slate (or slate3k for Python3)- this is not really stable though so you may have some issues with the install and running it. I did eventually get it to work and I was able to extract text when Py2PDF failed.

[Slate](https://github.com/TakesxiSximada/slate3k)

A good code I use to clean up JPEG files before inputting to tesseract- improves text output accuracy. Also has code on how you would read in the JPEG to tesseract: [Here](https://github.com/yardstick17/image_text_reader/blob/master/read_image.py)

If you have Mac OSX you can use an `os.system` command with sips to convert the pdf to jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 not support extract text from arabic pdf I was having the same problem and after some search i found library called pdfplumber which can extract the Arabic text
this is the code check it

```
import pdfplumber
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
with pdfplumber.open(r'example.pdf') as pdf:
    my_page = pdf.pages[10]
    thepages=my_page.extract_text()
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(thepages)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    print(bidi_text)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).